# Why doesn't this work? Does android not allow constructors?

Tags: android, class, constructor, timer, android-intent

I am wonder why this code doesn't work. Is it because of the constructor?

```
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.Window;
import android.widget.TextView;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.app.Activity;
import java.util.Timer;
import java.util.TimerTask;

public class ClockMain extends Activity {

int Hours;
int Minutes;
int Seconds;

String TimeOfDayS;

TextView HoursMainV;
TextView MinutesMainV;
TextView SecondsMainV;
TextView TimeOfDayMainV;

Timer oneSecond;

public ClockMain(int Seconds) {
    // TODO Auto-generated constructor stub
    oneSecond = new Timer();
    oneSecond.schedule(new SecondsTask(), Seconds * 1000);

}
class SecondsTask extends TimerTask {
    public void run() {
        new ClockMain(1);
        ++Seconds;
        if(Seconds == 60){
            ++Minutes;
            Seconds = 0;
            if(Minutes == 60) {
                ++Hours;
                Minutes = 0;
                if(Hours == 12){
                    if(TimeOfDayS.equals("AM")) {
                        TimeOfDayS = "PM";
                    } else{
                        TimeOfDayS = "AM";
                    }
                    Hours= 0;
                }
            }
        }
        HoursMainV = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.HoursMainV);
        HoursMainV.setText(""+Hours);

        MinutesMainV = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.MinutesMainV);
        MinutesMainV.setText(":"+Minutes);

        SecondsMainV = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.SecondsMainV);
        SecondsMainV.setText(":"+Seconds);

        TimeOfDayMainV = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.TimeOfDayMainV);
        TimeOfDayMainV.setText(" "+TimeOfDayS);
    }
}
public void onCreate(Bundle bundle) {
    super.onCreate(bundle);
    setContentView(R.layout.clock_main);
    requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);

    Bundle extras = getIntent().getExtras();
        if (extras == null) {
            return;
        }
    int Hour = extras.getInt("HoursS");
    Hour = Hours;
    int Minute = extras.getInt("MinutesS");
    Minute = Minutes;
    int Second = extras.getInt("SecondsS");
    Second = Seconds;
    String TimeOfDaySs = extras.getString("TimeOfDayS");
    TimeOfDaySs = TimeOfDayS;
    HoursMainV = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.HoursMainV);
    HoursMainV.setText(""+Hour);

    MinutesMainV = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.MinutesMainV);
    MinutesMainV.setText(":"+Minute);

    SecondsMainV = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.SecondsMainV);
    SecondsMainV.setText(":"+Second);

    TimeOfDayMainV = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.TimeOfDayMainV);
    TimeOfDayMainV.setText(" "+TimeOfDaySs);
    new ClockMain(1);

}
  }
```

And yes I did change the Manifest and I know there is not a problem with the xml. It stopped running when I added the public Clock Main and the SecondsTask Class. Please help. If there is a better way of doing this specific to android, I would love to learn it or if I am missing something I would like to know that too.

Comment: If there is a better way of doing this specific to android? First write what you are trying to perform and whats exactly the problems you are facing. It would be better to understand

Comment: I am trying to create a clock. Just for fun.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Instead of passing `int seconds` in constructor,
You should pass it through `Intent` and in `onCreate()` of the `Activity` and then you can start and schedule the timer for this `Activity`.

`onCreate()` may be considered as Constructor for the `Activity`.

Comment: [For few more details](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3302177/android-activity-constructor-vs-oncreate)

Comment: Alright. I am a little new so can you provide an example of what you are talking about please? Thank you very much.

Answer (score 0):

I think, the problem is with the views that are being updated in your SecondsTask run() method. TimerTask runs in a separate thread. In android, only the main thread can update the UI. You are updating the UI from a worker thread. So remove that UI updation task from this run method. To update the UI, use Handlers or runOnUiThread methods...
I hope you got the asnswer....