# NullPointerException when accessing constructor

Tags: java, android, oop, constructor, nullpointerexception

I feel like either I'm missing a vital point in OOP, or my constructor is wrong. I keep getting a null pointer exception when creating my object.

The logcat is saying that its coming from the first line of the '// default constructor'.

Here is the code for my class:

```
package com.chriswahlfeldt.homeworkapp;

        import android.app.Activity;
        import android.view.View;
        import android.widget.EditText;

public class MyHomework extends Activity {

    private EditText title, description;
    private View homeworkView, activityView;

    // default constructor
    public MyHomework() {

        homeworkView = getLayoutInflater().inflate(R.layout.add_homework, null);
        activityView = getLayoutInflater().inflate(R.layout.activity_my, null);

        title = (EditText) homeworkView.findViewById(R.id.classTitleET);
        title.setText("");

        description = (EditText) homeworkView.findViewById(R.id.descriptionET);
        title.setText("");

    }

    public View getContentView_activity_my() { return activityView; }

    public View getContentView_add_homework() { return homeworkView; }

    public String getTitleTxt() { return title.getText().toString(); }

    public String getDescriptionTxt() { return description.getText().toString(); }

    public void setTitleTxt(String thatString) { title.setText(thatString); }

    public void setDescriptionTxt(String thatString) { title.setText(thatString); }
}
```

And here is where it is used:

```
package com.chriswahlfeldt.homeworkapp;

        import android.app.Activity;
        import android.os.Bundle;
        import android.view.View;
        import android.widget.Button;

public class MyActivity extends Activity
{

    private MyHomework hW = new MyHomework();

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        setContentView(hW.getContentView_activity_my());

        final Button addHWBtn = (Button) findViewById(R.id.HWBtn);

        addHWBtn.setOnClickListener(
                new View.OnClickListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onClick(View view) {
                        setContentView(hW.getContentView_add_homework());
                    }
                });
    }
}
```

.xml file: activity_my.xml

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="wrap_content"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
tools:context=".MyActivity"
android:id="@+id/mainRelLayout" >

    <Button
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/HWBtn"
        android:textSize="25sp"
        android:paddingLeft="50dp"
        android:paddingRight="50dp"
        android:paddingTop="10dp"
        android:paddingBottom="10dp"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
        android:hint="+Homework"/>

</RelativeLayout>
```

.xml file: add_homework.xml

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent" android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:alpha=".8">

    <EditText
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:inputType="textPersonName"
        android:ems="10"
        android:id="@+id/classTitleET"
        android:layout_gravity="top"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
        android:capitalize="sentences"
        android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
        android:layout_marginBottom="10dp"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
        android:layout_marginRight="10dp"
        android:hint="Class Title"
        android:textSize="20sp" />

    <EditText
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:inputType="textMultiLine"
        android:ems="8"
        android:id="@+id/descriptionET"
        android:layout_below="@+id/classTitleET"
        android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/classTitleET"
        android:layout_alignStart="@+id/classTitleET"
        android:layout_alignRight="@+id/classTitleET"
        android:layout_alignEnd="@+id/classTitleET"
        android:hint="Homework Description"
        android:textSize="20sp"
        android:height="120dp"
        android:gravity="top" />

    <Button
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/createBtn"
        android:hint="Create"
        android:textSize="20sp"
        android:layout_below="@+id/descriptionET"
        android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/descriptionET"
        android:layout_alignStart="@+id/descriptionET"
        android:layout_alignRight="@+id/descriptionET"
        android:layout_alignEnd="@+id/descriptionET" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

Thx!

Comment: this would be a good [reference](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3302177/android-activity-constructor-vs-oncreate)

Comment: Also, [don't pass null to `inflate()`!](http://www.doubleencore.com/2013/05/layout-inflation-as-intended/)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

yout can't call getLayoutInflater() directly , you need to call it on an instance of the LayoutInflater class.
try this

```
LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater) context.getSystemService( Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE );
homeworkView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.add_homework, null);
```

you can replace context with "this" if you are calling this inan activity

Comment: This worked but I had to pass a Context to my constructor when creating the object in the on create. Thx for pushing me in the right direction!

Comment: @waffles its probably better that you read the [reference material on Activities](http://developer.android.com/guide/components/activities.html) before continuing - Android doesn't like it when you use the main constructor and  prefers that you use onCreate() etc

Answer (score 2):

It's a bad practice to put the code inside a constructor for activities. You can put in the OnCreate method.

If you need this instance really.

You can do the following

```
public class MyHomework extends Activity {

    private EditText title, description;
    private View homeworkView, activityView;
    private static MyHomework instance;
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
         instance = this;
    }
    public static MyHomework getActivity() {
         return instance;
    }
}
```

```
public class MyActivity extends Activity
{

    private MyHomework hW = MyHomework.getActivity();

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        .....
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

1. You cannot call activity methods or use the activity as a `Context` before `onCreate()` in the activity lifecycle. Instance initialization including constructor is too early. As a consequence, you rarely need to use an explicit constructor with activities.
2. Never instantiate activity classes with `new`. Related to the point above: such objects are not really good for anything since they are not properly initialized as activities and their activity lifecycle methods such as `onCreate()` are not invoked.

It looks like your `MyHomework` should not be an activity at all:

- Remove the `extends Activity``
- Pass in a `Context` as an argument to methods that need it. For example,

  ```
  public MyHomework(Context context) {
      homeworkView = LayoutInflater.from(context).inflate(...)
  ```

  Invocation from `MyActivity` `onCreate()` (not member variable init, too early):

  ```
  homework = new MyHomework(this)
  ```