# Using shared preferences between fragment and activity

Tags: java, android, android-studio, android-fragments

Im trying to use shared prefernces between my first activity and a fragment stationed on my second activity. The code shows what I have done so far but I am having problems getting the context. I also think what I am doing wont work so just want some quick help. Thanks

> Attempt to invoke virtual method 'android.content.Context
>   android.content.Context.getApplicationContext()' on a null object
>   reference

**READ PREFS**

```
 sharedPreferences =  getSharedPreferences("alexcz", MODE_PRIVATE);
 String drawableString = sharedPreferences.getString("PARTICLE_TYPE", "null")
```

---

**WRITE PREF**

```
 public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_particle_type, container, false);

        white_blur = (ImageButton)view.findViewById(R.id.white_blur);
        green_blur = (ImageButton)view.findViewById(R.id.green_blur);
        orange_blur = (ImageButton)view.findViewById(R.id.orange_blur);
        pink_blur = (ImageButton)view.findViewById(R.id.pink_blur);
        yellow_blur = (ImageButton)view.findViewById(R.id.yellow_blur);
        blue_blur = (ImageButton)view.findViewById(R.id.blue_blur);

        main main = new main();
        Context context = main.getApplicationContext();

        sharedPref = context.getSharedPreferences("alexcz", main.MODE_PRIVATE);
        editor = sharedPref.edit();

 editor.putString("PARTICLE_TYPE", "white_blur");

        setOnClickListeners();
        return view;
    }
```

Comment: You're not actually writing anywhere. You're not using `editor`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Never do this : `main main = new main();`. Instead do:

```
Context context = getActivity().getApplicationContext();
```

If you wish to access `applicationContext` inside of the fragment. When you initialize Android activities with a constructor, everything gets messed up, just don't do it. Refer to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3302177/android-activity-constructor-vs-oncreate)

Answer (score 0):

Just replace these lines:

```
main main = new main();
Context context = main.getApplicationContext();
sharedPref = context.getSharedPreferences("alexcz", main.MODE_PRIVATE);
```

with:

```
sharedPref = getActivity().getSharedPreferences("alexcz", getActivity().MODE_PRIVATE);
editor = sharedPref.edit();
```

`getActivity().MODE_PRIVATE` will show a warning for accessing `static` member via `instance`.